# Qt: Using "setContextProperty" with "QObject" and "JavaScriptOwnership" causes item to be collected/deleted

Tags: qt, garbage-collection, qml

I am integrating QML and .NET. ([project link](https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet))

When I send .NET objects to QML, I wrap it with a `NetValue : public QObject` C++ type.

The `NetValue` type stores a strong reference to the underlying .NET object to prevent .NET GC while active in QML.

I use `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(netValue, QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);` so that QML will delete `NetValue` when it is done with it. I then use `NetValue::~NetValue()` to tell .NET to release the strong reference.

This has worked well for me so far, but I am running into an issue. Consider the following.

```
QObject* testObject = new TestObject();
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(testObject, QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("testObject", testObject);
```

At a certain point, my `TestObject` will be destroyed.

I would expect `setContextProperty` to hold a strong reference to the `QObject` type, preventing it from being GC'd in QML.

Using `QQmlEngine::CppOwnership` fixes the issue, but as I've explained previously, I need to use `QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership` to track the lifetime of the wrapping QML type that holds a reference to the .NET object.

Why doesn't `setContextProperty` store a strong reference (increase ref count, or something) to my `QObject` that I pass it?

Comment: maybe passing the smart pointer to QML instead of GC?

Comment: Doesn't work. QML only accepts a naked QObject.

Comment: Just out of interest, what the purpose of your project? What is missing in Qt / QML so you need to add some.NET functionality? Or perhaps vice versa. As for the question - don't you think that setting an object as a context property of QQmlEngine suggests that its life cycle should be managed by QQmlEngine, not by JS?

Comment: the smart pointer can be passed by `QVariant::fromValue` but the object can't be used...

Comment: @folibis, there is no good cross-plat solution for GUI in .NET Core. Also, .NET has activate libraries for many things QML doesn't provide, such as building web services, consuming web services, database providers (MongoDB, Oracle, etc), etc, etc etc. I personally have my entire business logic inside of .NET and use QML strictly for the UI layer (click event handlers, animations, etc).

Comment: Hey, I just encountered the same problem but with c++. Fortunately, I can create an object in a smart pointer and pass it to context as `objectPointer.data()` at it won't get deleted until application end. Unfortunately, now I have to rely on qt c++ parent relations for all my c++ objects to get them alive and deleted at the right time.